# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen "vorhersagen" und "voraussagen" bzw. "vorhersehen" und "voraussehen"?

Tags: meaning, difference, verb

Ich wüsste gerne den Unterschied zwischen *vorhersagen* und *voraussagen* sowie auch zwischen *vorhersehen* und *voraussehen*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Diese Verben sind einander so ähnlich, dass es nur eine Geschmacksfrage ist, welches man einsetzt.

> Sie sagte ihm eine große Zukunft voraus.
>
> Sie sagte ihm eine große Zukunft vorher.

Ich erkenne keinen Bedeutungsunterschied, würde hier aber eher *voraussagen* verwenden. Andere sehen das anders. Allerdings gewinnt z.B. *die Wettervorhersage* gegenüber der *Wettervoraussage* 1.000.000 zu 0.

---

Ähnlich ist es mit *vorhersehen* und *voraussehen*.

> Das war vorauszusehen.
>
> Das war vorherzusehen.

Wieder kein Bedeutungsunterschied.

Comment: Ich meine, theoretisch und sprachgeschichtlich sollte es einen Unterschied geben. (Aber ich gebe zu, dass er in der Sprachpraxis des frühen 21. Jahrhunderts offensichtlich keine Rolle spielt.) Der Unterschied müsste ähnlich sein wie bei den kontrastierenden Bedeutungen von *hinaus* und *heraus*, also *weg von hier* vs. *hierher*. Dann wäre *vorhersehen* verwendbar für Dinge, die *her*kommen (die Zukunft, wenn man davon ausgeht, dass wir stehen und die Zukunft sich uns nähert) und *voraussehen*... äh... ach nein... Unsinn.

Comment: voraussehen hat für mich manchmal einen planenden, bestimmten Charakter, während die anderen 3 Begriffe eher ins Wage, Ungewisse gehen. Jemand, der sehr voraussehend ist, plant gut. Die anderen 3 Begriffe passen da nicht so rein, finde ich

Comment: Alex hat vollkommen recht. Man kann beispielsweise jemanden für seine *voraussehende Fahrweise* loben oder etwas in einem Traum *vorhersehen*. Hier sind die Begriffe keineswegs austauschbar.

Comment: Ich kenne nur eine *voraus**schau**ende*, Fahrweise, keine *voraussehende*. Und in einem Traum sehe ich Dinge selbstverständlich nur *voraus*, nicht *vorher*. Das ist eine Geschmacksfrage.

Comment: Nach meinem Sprachgefühl passt das Dativobjekt besser zu *voraussagen*. Zu *vorhersagen* passt das Dativobjekt für mich nicht so gut.